# Shopware 6.5: Failed scheduled tasks, output missing

Tags: symfony, shopware6

I have updated Shopware to version 6.5 and noticed that enqueue and therefore the DB table `dead_messages` is not available anymore.

My scheduled task got the status `failed` when it ran. Where can I see why the task fails now?

The file `config/packages/messenger.yaml` is not configured other than the default. The Symfony docs, in my opinion, does not explain if and how I can log and analyze failing scheduled tasks properly. How does this work in 6.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to find the messages in the `messenger_messages` table if you use the default queue settings.

As in shopware 6.5 a lot of custom queue handling was removed, so the default symfony queue and also failure and retry handling is used now. So the best place to search for more info probably is the [symfony docs][1].

is
[1]: https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#retries-failures

Comment: In my case `messenger_messages` is empty, but the ScheduledTask has the status `failed`. In my server/phplogs is nothing. There must be some output for failed tasks, but where is it?

Comment: I have no idea, why I do see failed messages in the database now... It has not worked last week... Thanks.